# Stripe redirectToCheckout handle result (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, stripe-payments

I have code to make payment using Stripe checkout

Here is code

```
async pay(price: number, name: string, description: string) {
    const stripe = await loadStripe('***************');
    this._subscriptionService.createStripeSession(price, name, description, this.document.location.origin)
    .subscribe(async result => {
        this.sessionId = result;
        const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: this.sessionId
        });
    });
}
```

Now it works well and after the success I go to SuccesUrl, that defined in session, that created on back end.

But also I need to catch the result of function and run another function. How I can do this?

**UPDATE**

Here is `createStripeSession`

```
createStripeSession(price: number | null | undefined, name: string | null | undefined, description: string | null | undefined, locationUrl: string | null | undefined): Observable<string> {
    let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/Subscription/CreateStripeSession?";
    if (price !== undefined)
        url_ += "price=" + encodeURIComponent("" + price) + "&"; 
    if (name !== undefined)
        url_ += "name=" + encodeURIComponent("" + name) + "&"; 
    if (description !== undefined)
        url_ += "description=" + encodeURIComponent("" + description) + "&"; 
    if (locationUrl !== undefined)
        url_ += "locationUrl=" + encodeURIComponent("" + locationUrl) + "&"; 
    url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

    let options_ : any = {
        observe: "response",
        responseType: "blob",
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "application/json"
        })
    };

    return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
        return this.processCreateStripeSession(response_);
    })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
        if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
            try {
                return this.processCreateStripeSession(<any>response_);
            } catch (e) {
                return <Observable<string>><any>_observableThrow(e);
            }
        } else
            return <Observable<string>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `redirectToCheckout` function to return an `Observable` and then you can subscribe to it.

```
    async pay(price: number, name: string, description: string) {
        const stripe = await loadStripe('***************');
        this._subscriptionService.createStripeSession(price, name, description, this.document.location.origin)
        .subscribe(async result => {
            this.sessionId = result;
            const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
                sessionId: this.sessionId
            }).subscribe(result2 =>{
               //run another function code here
            });
        });
    }
```

Converting `Promise` to `Observable` in your `redirectToCheckout` function

```
    import { from } from 'rxjs';

    redirectToCheckout(){
      return from(your promise code in here);
    }
```

Comment: `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ error: StripeError; }>'.`

I have this error when try to write this code

Comment: @EugeneSukh show your `createStripeSession` and `redirectToCheckout`function

Comment: It is because it returns a `Promise`. Convert your promise to an `Observable`.

Comment: How I can do this? using `from(promise)`?

Comment: Updated my answer for you.